# error:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in xcode about opencv

Tags: objective-c, xcode, opencv, opencv3.0

Below is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat image;
    image = imread("/Users/Desktop/lena.jpg", 1);
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Display Image", image);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

i run it, but i get the following error

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please include your code or error in your question, a screenshot of text fields is almost always unnecessary (especially when the text is about 10-lines long ).

Comment: Fixed issue with images not displaying properly. Copied code from image into code block for ease